# AdMob area is not clickable after being hidden

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've a tableview which displays advertisement if user is NOT premium. But in this case if the user IS premium I'm hiding the advertisement by adding this code:

```
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError)
{
    advertisementBanner.isHidden = true
    topConstraint.constant = 0

    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.updateConstraints()
}
```

So, when I run this code and the advertisement is hidden I can't still tap on the area where the advertisement is located. Its like its still there but hidden, and I've no idea how I can solve this issue.

So my question is: How can I make the area where my ad is located clickable if the ad is NOT shown? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: What you do after click ?

Comment: @dahiya_boy How do you mean?

Comment: You said **How can I make the area where my ad is located clickable**. After click what you do?

Comment: Take a look at the picture: https://i.imgur.com/Fxd7ddP.png    -    I cannot tap on the "Support" and "Logga ut" because that's the area where the advertisement is normally shown. (Hidden now because I'm premium)

Comment: Run your project & then Open your same screen, then click on **Debug view heirarchy**. Check https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHhro.png . After that it will tell you if there is any view in your screen ahead on tableview in that portion. [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)

Comment: @dahiya_boy There is. https://imgur.com/vv0MwRr

Comment: @dahiya_boy So, how can I fix that? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`advertisementBanner.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: If UI component is hidden then you dont need to explicitly do disable isUserInteractionEnabled. Your answer does not make  sense.

Comment: You can try to remove this view from superView if you don't need it. Or you can add bottom constraint to tableView to abView top.